# Female voice using MCI voice commands?

Tags: vb6, voice, mci

Can MCI voice control in VB6 produce a female voice using MCI voice commands?

It works fine now but only in a male's voice.

Comment: Take a look at [Speech SDK 5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10121)